# A CNAME record can't be set up for the domain root

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, namecheap

I recently bought a new domain from namecheap and decided to delegate it to Yandex.Connect services, so I changed namecheap's DNS to custom, added Yandex' nameservers (`dns1.yandex.net` and `dns2.yandex.net`) in the control panel, added the proof and within a couple hours my domain was being managed by Yandex.

Since I am hosting a personal site in my own premises and since my ISP doesn't sell any static IPs I decided to use DDNS. But when I tried to add a CNAME for `@` that points to `my-domain.example-ddns.org` I found out it does... nothing. The record just isn't being created. I tried adding another one for a subdomain and it works perfectly fine.

After reading [Yandex' guides](https://yandex.com/support/domain/domain/dns.html#dns__dns-editor) I read this:

> CNAME. Remember that a CNAME record can't be set up for the domain root, because this is prohibited by the RFC.

Imagine my shock when I read such a thing, when at the same time I have another domain registered with namecheap, but using namecheap's basic DNS instead, where I set up a CNAME record for @ that points to `my-other-domain.example-ddns.org` and it works perfectly fine!

How do I work around this? Using an A record is a no-go since I can't get an static IP.

Comment: Why the downvote, though? Does this not belong in here? At least point me in the right direction

Comment: Agreed. A downvote without commenting is rather pointless.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way around this. Per [RFC 1912](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt):

```
2.4 CNAME records
    A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data.
```

However, the apex of any zone *MUST* contain other data, such as SOA and NS records, which is why a CNAME cannot exist at the top.

Therefore, you generally have to resort to an A record rather than a CNAME; there are exceptions to this, however, in cases where the domain is being hosted by server capable of dynamically generating the A records. For example, EasyDNS has a way around this using a proprietary implementation of an "ANAME" record, described [here](https://fusion.easydns.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/190/7/aname-records). A standard, RFC-compliant nameserver will not support this feature directly, however.

Comment: So if I was able to add a `CNAME` record for host `@` with a value of `my-domain.example-ddns.org`, it means Namecheap is doing something like what you say under the hood?

Comment: I'm not so sure. Even [namecheap's own documentation](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9646/2237/how-can-i-set-up-a-cname-record-for-my-domain) says you shouldn't do this. If you have, and it works, it may just be luck.

Comment: Case closed, then